# Having a domain that both has shopify and cpanel backend

Tags: shopify, cpanel

Is it possible for a domain to both have shopify and cpanel backend?

I have a shopify domain that is bought from shopify and im planning to connect it to my cpanel so i can run php coded pages.

Answer (score 0):

No. Shopify hosts Shopify. You cannot get access to that. Instead, use your CPanel to create an App. Host your App. Use CPanel to control your App. If you want your App to support your Shopify store, simply install your App in the Shopify store using their APIs. With that, you can fully integrate yourself into a Shopify store, using CPanel, remembering that your App code functions inside Shopify using the available APIs they offer you.